# Run upstart task on file change?

Tags: upstart, inotify, inotifywait

Here's my attempt:

```
start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo and file EVENT=modify FILE="/tmp/bar.txt")

task

script
  chdir /tmp
  exec echo THIS_CHANGED >> CHANGEDDDDDDDD
end script
```

But it only runs once. How do I make it run whenever `/tmp/bar.txt` is modified?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty crappy solution, but this is all I've been able to get working:

```
start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)

script
  chdir /tmp
  while inotifywait -e modify "/tmp/bar.txt"; do
    echo THIS_CHANGED >> CHANGEDDDDDDDD
  done
end script
```

Would much prefer not to add my own `inotify` watchers; and instead use the system level one.